# Edit form controls with GemBox.Document

Tags: c#, docx, form-fields, gembox-document

How can we write or modify existing values of form controls in Word documents using GemBox.Document?
I found the examples for [creating](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-create-word-form/701) and [reading](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-read-word-form/702), but I just cannot find one for writing...

I tried using this:

```
// Input file from 'reading' example.
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("FormFilled.docx");
FormFieldDataCollection formData = document.Content.FormFieldsData;

FormFieldData fullNameData = formData.First(ffd => ffd.Name == "FullName");

// I cannot do this, FormFieldData.Value is read only!
fullNameData.Value = "My Name";
```

But `FormFieldData.Value` has only `get`, so is this possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, try this:

```
DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load("FormFilled.docx");
// Get a snapshot of all form fields in the document.
FormFieldDataCollection formData = document.Content.FormFieldsData;

// Edit "FullName" text box field.
FormTextData fullNameData = (FormTextData)formData["FullName"];
fullNameData.Field.ResultInlines.Content.LoadText("Jane Doe");

// Edit "BirthDate" text box field.
FormTextData birthDateData = (FormTextData)formData["BirthDate"];
birthDateData.Field.ResultInlines.Content.LoadText(
    new DateTime(2000, 1, 1).ToString(birthDateData.ValueFormat));

// Edit "Salary" text box field.
FormTextData salaryData = (FormTextData)formData["Salary"];
salaryData.Field.ResultInlines.Content.LoadText(
    5432.1.ToString(salaryData.ValueFormat));

// Uncheck "Married" check box field.
FormCheckBoxData marriedData = (FormCheckBoxData)formData["Married"];
marriedData.Value = false;

// Select "Female" from drop down field, note that "genderData.Items
// contains a list of drop down field's items that you can select.
FormDropDownData genderData = (FormDropDownData)formData["Gender"];
genderData.SelectedItemIndex = 2;

document.Save("FormFilledOutput.docx");
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

In one of a newer GemBox.Document's bug fix versions the [FormTextData.Value](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/help/html/P_GemBox_Document_FormTextData_Value.htm) property has both getter and setter, so the above can be simplified with the following:

```
// Edit "FullName" text box field.
FormTextData fullNameData = (FormTextData)formData["FullName"];
fullNameData.Value = "Jane Doe";

// Edit "BirthDate" text box field.
FormTextData birthDateData = (FormTextData)formData["BirthDate"];
birthDateData.Value = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

// Edit "Salary" text box field.
FormTextData salaryData = (FormTextData)formData["Salary"];
salaryData.Value = 5432.1;
```

Also you can refer to [this example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-update-word-form/703).

Comment: Thanks Mario, it helps!